# Unqualified name in IDL for imported type library

Tags: c++, com, namespaces, idl

I've created a COM-class that implements some interface. I want to add a method to this interface. The parameter of this method is a pointer to the interface defined in some external olb-file. In my project this olb-file imported without `no_namespace` directive. So, the interface name in the parameter of the method must be qualified in h\cpp files. But MIDL doesn't recognize namespaces and generates header file with unqualified interface in the method. So, error C2061. A little sample:

```
//stdafx.h
#import "somelib.olb" named_guids no_function_mapping
```

In somelib.olb defined interface `Foo`. It's qualified name in my project is `someLib::Foo`

```
//myproject.idl
...
[
  object,
  uuid(...),
  ...
]
library MyProjectLib
{
  importlib(somelib.olb);
  ...
  [
     object,
     uuid(...),
     helpstring(...),
     pointer_default(unique)
  ]
  interface IMyInterface : IUnknown{
     [propputref, helpstring("...")] HRESULT Bar ([in] IFoo* Parent);
  };
```

MIDL generates header file MyProject.h

```
//MyProject.h
...
IMyInterface : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual /* [helpstring][propputref] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE putref_Bar( 
        /* [in] */ /* external definition not present */ IFoo *Parent) = 0;
};
...
```

And error message

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IFoo'
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why don't you use no_namespace?

Comment: Many olb-files are imported. It was decision to avoid name collisions

Comment: `rename("IFoo", "someLib::IFoo")`?